# Aptana Studio 3 で検索するときにdevelopment.logが検索対象から外れない

Tags: aptana

Aptana Studio 3 (build: 3.6.0.201407100658) でプロジェクトの中から特定の文字列を検索するときに、

[image: Sarch]

としてdevelopment.logを検索対象から外そうとしているんですが、ガッツリ検索してしまいます。
何か指定の仕方が間違っているんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!x` で `x` を除外すると書かれていますから、 `development.log` を除外するためには `!development.log` と指定するのではないでしょうか。

Comment: あーそういうこと
!x development.log
ってデフォルトで入っていたような気がしていたので、これが正しいと思い込んでました。
ありがとうございました。